# How can I use .bss section of memory(for global variables) for assembly(armv8) program properly?

Tags: c, assembly, armv8

Here's how I wrote it on my code:

```
     .section .text
fmt:          .string "x \t\t ln(x)\n"
sfmt:         .string "%.10lf \t %.10lf\n"
error:        .string "Error"
filename:     .string "input.bin"

     .section .data
LIM:          .double 0r1.0E-13
zero:         .double 0r0.0
one:          .double 0r1.0
half:         .double 0r0.5
x_arr:        .skip   98*8
```

...(rest of my code that I think works well. I isolated this part cause this is the part that causes segmentation fault whenever I compile+link+run my executable.Also, the x_arr was initially at .bss section but I keep on getting segfault and whenever I try to do layout reg in gdb, nothing comes up.)

Rest of the code that may cause the problem on the whole program:

```
define(i_r,w19)
define(j_r,w20)
define(n_r,w21)
define(fd_r,w22)
define(ln_x,w8)
define(cur_term,d9)
define(n_read,x25)
define(x_j,d10)

BUF_SIZE = 98*8
AT_FDCWD = -100
O_RDONLY = 0
ln_size = 8
cur_term_size = 8
x_j_size = 8

fp    .req    x29
lr    .req    x30

alloc = -(16+ln_size+cur_term_size+x_j_size) & -16
dealloc = -alloc

      .balign 4
      .global main
      .type main,%function

main:    stp    fp,lr,[sp,alloc]!
         mov    fp,sp

         ldp    fp,lr,[sp],dealloc
         ret
```

Comment: This looks correct but may require some extra alignment directives.  What is the rest of your program?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'll update it hang on a sec

Comment: I only added the main part cause it always says that at the start of the main(stp fp,lr,...), the sigsegv signal generates whenever I use the gdb.

Comment: That's not a [mcve].  I cannot compile and run it to find out what the problem is.  Please cut out everything that is not needed to reproduce the problem but leave a program that can be compiled and run.  This makes it so much easier to help you.

Comment: alright hang on a second

Comment: Already did update it

Comment: Your code does not reference any of the variables. Those should have no effect and the code shown should work and does here. Make sure the code you have provided actually crashes, even outside gdb.

Comment: yes because I have to minimally reproduce the error and even though I didn't apply the variables, I keep on getting the same segmentation fault

Comment: @Elo The code you posted works flawlessly on my system.  Make sure you tested it correctly!  It is possible that you accidentally tested an old binary.

Comment: okay so I did this: m4 a6v2.asm > a6v2.s then gcc -o a6v2 a6v2.s to create the executable then gdb a6v2 then 'r' to run inside gdb

Comment: Does it crash **outside** of gdb? From earlier question it sounds like your gdb is broken.

Comment: oh shoot I havent checked that

Comment: @Jester, and yes Ive tried outside gdb just by running the executable. It still says segfault

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to switch back to `.text` before emitting code. That may put your instructions into non-executable memory and hence fault. Would also explain gdb being reluctant to accept your `main` as a function.

Comment: @Jester, you mean before the .balign 4 line?

Comment: Yes that would be a good place.

Comment: This is the one causing the segfault dang it. Thanks again for the help man!

Comment: @Elo Cool!  Good to have found the problem.

Comment: @Jester, last question man, why does the rest have to be switched to .text?

Comment: As I said, `.data` is not executable. `.text` is the place for code.